# Stop Automatic Action/Autoplay on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

It used to be, after connecting my tablet to my PC, a pop-up window/menu would appear giving my several options (i.e. open as a folder and some others). On the bottom there was a check box that said something like "Do this action automatically". I checked it. Now the action is done automatically.

How do I turn this automatic action off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Control Panel, then AutoPlay, then the rest is self-explanatory.

OR

Hit windows key. In the search box enter 'gpedit.msc' (admin password required).
Navigate to:

```
User configuration
  > Administrative templates
    > Windows components
      > Autoplay policies
```

In the right pane, click 'turn off autoplay' and make it disabled.

Comment: yes, thank you, I just can't accept your answer until ~10 minutes have passed

Comment: actually I liked your first answer better, it solved my problem and was dead simple, please add it back

Comment: this second answer I have tried before but got lost in my memory so I offered the easier answer first. thanks for the feedback.